# Replace special characters in a string with _ (underscore)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove special characters from a string and replace them with the `_` character.

For example:

```
string = "img_realtime_tr~ading3$"
```

The resulting string should look like "img_realtime_tr_ading3_";

I need to replace those characters: `& / \ # , + ( ) $ ~ % .. ' " : * ? < > { }`

Comment: why is this closed, it's a good question. How to replace special characters, useful when making SE-friendly URL's. Thankfully still someone replied to it.

Comment: An extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet ? Well let's just say that at least 108 persons where thinking otherwise.

Comment: Closed ? Pretty useful when scraping dirty data though.

Comment: This should not be closed

Answer (score 274):

```
string = string.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g,'_');
```

Alternatively, to change all characters except numbers and letters, try:

```
string = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'_');
```

Comment: Cool! `!` is missing in the first line though.

Comment: Second line is very useful in a number of occasions.

Comment: ``\-`` and ``=`` also missing :)

Comment: If you have a special character before a space like `hello! word` you will end up with two underscore consecutive like this `hello__word` so, you can do this:
`string = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'_').replace(/__/g,'_');`

Comment: @DannyFeliz or even
`string = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'_').replace(/_{2,}/g,'_');` if you do not know how many consecutive underscores

Comment: what does g mean??

Comment: @AnilKumarReddy the g modifier is used to perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match).

Comment: The second variant will drop French or other languages characters

Answer (score 10):

```
string = string.replace(/[\W_]/g, "_");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myStr = "img_realtime_tr~ading3$ #Amoos !"

const replaceAccentsChars = (str, charWith='-', regexType='NO_SPECIAL' ) => {
  
    if(!str) return
  
    const REGEX_TYPE = {
      'ALL': / /g,
      'NO_SPECIAL': /[^A-Z0-9]/ig,
      'SINGLE_FOR_MULTI': /[^A-Z0-9]+/ig,
    }

    return str.replace(REGEX_TYPE[regexType], charWith).toLowerCase()
}


console.log(
  replaceAccentsChars(myStr)
)

// Speical Chars Allowed & String as params
console.log(
  replaceAccentsChars(myStr, '*', 'ALL')
)

console.log(
  replaceAccentsChars(myStr, '_', 'SINGLE_FOR_MULTI')
)
```